# Require instead of if for input validation

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, remix

Why is it preferred to use require instead of if for input validation/checks of functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if` is only half the equation:

```
if (msg.sender != owner) {
    // What goes here?
}
```

If you're going to put a `revert()` in there to abort the transaction, that's equivalent to:

```
require(msg.sender == owner);
```

The latter is a bit shorter, and, though this is a matter of opinion, I find it easier to read positive assertions ("sender must be owner" as opposed to "abort if sender is not owner").